# Unitary transformation of group of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to define a set of new matrices $\{B\}$ as a unitary transformation of $\{A\}$. $B$ is 3 by 3 and $A$ is of course 3 by 3.

Given a 10 by 10 unitary matrix $u$, if 
$B_i = \sum_{k=1}^{10}u_{ki} A_k$,

does it mean:

1. $A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{10}u_{ki}B_i$
2. $A_i = \sum_{k=1}^{10}u_{ik}B_k$
3. $A_k = \sum_{k=1}^{10}u_{ki}^{*}B_i$

Answer (score 1):

You're not really using the matrix structure of the $A$'s and $B$'s, just treating them as vectors.
You have $(B_1, \ldots, B_{10}) = (A_1, \ldots, A_{10}) { u}$, so
$(A_1, \ldots, A_{10}) = (B_1, \ldots, B_{10}) { u}^{-1} = (B_1, \ldots, B_{10} {\bf u}^*$
i.e.
$$ A_k = \sum_{i=1}^{10} B_i \overline{u_{ki}}$$